# wpf - Binding properties to an array code behing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, code-behind

I have to create many controls on runtime and i need to bind to an array, but they doesn't bind.

In the code we can assume that I get 3 nameplates, but when I type data into or select an item they don't set it in the property

View

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
        int top = 10;
        int position = 0;

        foreach (NameplateModel nameplate in _nameplateList)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Content = nameplate.FieldName;
            lbl.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            lbl.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            lbl.Margin = new Thickness(0, top, 0, 0);
            grid.Children.Add(lbl);


            if (nameplate.LookupValue !=null && nameplate.LookupValue.Count() > 0)
            {
                ComboBox cbo = new ComboBox();
                cbo.ItemsSource = nameplate.LookupValue;
                Binding b = new Binding();
                b.Source = DataContext;
                b.Path = new PropertyPath("TextValues[0]");
                b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
                b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                cbo.SetBinding(ComboBox.TextProperty,b);

                if (!nameplate.LimitToList)
                {
                    cbo.IsEditable = true;
                }
                cbo.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                cbo.Margin = new Thickness(98,top,0,0);
                cbo.Width = 174;
                cbo.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                grid.Children.Add(cbo);
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                Binding b = new Binding();
                b.Source = DataContext;
                b.Path = new PropertyPath(string.Format("TextValues[{0}]", position));
                b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
                b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                txt.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, b);
                txt.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                txt.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                txt.Width = 174;
                txt.Margin = new Thickness(98, top, 0, 0);
                grid.Children.Add(txt);
            }
            top = top + 29;
            position++;
        }
        scvNameplate.Content = grid;
```

and my ViewModel

```
public string[] TextValues
    {
        get
        {
            return _textValues ?? (_textValues =  new string[3]);
        }
        set
        {
            _textValues = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TextValues");
        }
    }
```

NameplateModel

```
public class NameplateModel
{
    #region Fields
    string _fieldName;
    string _lookupCode;
    string[] _lookupValue;
    bool _limitToList;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string FieldName
    {
        get
        {
            return _fieldName;
        }
        set
        {
            _fieldName = value;
        }
    }

    public string LookupCode
    {
        get
        {
            return _lookupCode;
        }
        set
        {
            _lookupCode = value;
        }
    }

    public string[] LookupValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _lookupValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _lookupValue = value;
        }
    }

    public bool LimitToList
    {
        get
        {
            return _limitToList;
        }
        set
        {
            _limitToList = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you dynamically creating these instead of using XAML? You are making things *way* harder than necessary.

Comment: I agree with the other guy. Why are you creating these controls in C#? Just stick an ItemsControl on the view and set its ItemsSource to your array and then specify the item template.

Comment: Show us the NameplateModel class.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET and SledgeHammer do you have some links to help me understand your solution, I am new on wpf and Brannon I will edit the question to add NameplateModel,

Comment: start [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/). Your method is so off I don't think I could write an answer :(

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That is nice, but doesn't resolve my problem, I need to bind multples controls to an array, but I don't know how can i do that and using the itemsControl via Xaml how can i bind each control to a position of the array ?

Comment: It works *automatically*. Items Controls bind to a collection and generate an ItemTemplate for each item in the collection (that is bound to it). They are awesome magic.

Comment: Consider chatting with us [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf) if you want to learn the *right* way to do this (after trying it and doing some research please :) )

Answer (score -1):

I got more than I was expecting, First I remove all the code behind and putted in Xaml on the ItemsControl

View

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NameplateList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="{Binding FieldName}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <ComboBox Text="{Binding TextValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding LookupValue}" IsEditable="{Binding LimitToList}" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextValue}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174" Margin="0,0,0,0" Visibility="{Binding IsVisibleText, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

and then just need to add the string TextValue property to take the value I need into the NameplateModel instead of having a TextValue[] on the viewModel

Now it works perfectly, Thanks @BradleyDotNET